# Sum of a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I do know the answer for the $a$ and $b$. The answer for $b$ is

$$2^n - 1.$$

But why is that the answer? Isn't the TOTAL price of the nth position  $1 + 2 + 2^2 + \ldots + 2^{n-1}$. How does that equal to $2^{n-1}$?

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, $1+2+2^2+...2^n=2^{n+1}-1$.

In fact, more generally, $1+a+a^2+...a^n=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$.

A familiar example is that the number composed of $n$ nines is one less than a $1$ followed by $n$ zeros.

Proof: multiply both sides by $a-1$, distribute the left hand side and you'll find almost all the terms cancel out.